# How to read all lines of a python input

Tags: python, python-3.x, for-loop, replace

I have this script to make character changes here, and add '.jpg' at the end of each line. Works well, but only identifies the first line, how do I identify and apply the treatment on all lines?

```
print('\033[1;33m<>'*50)
print('                         Conversor de Caracteres 0.0.1')
print('<>'*50)

texto = input(str('\033[1;30mDigite ou cole o texto:')).strip().lower()
print('\033[1;33mPROCESSANDO...')



#STEP DE ANÁLISE DE STR
texto = texto.replace(" ", "-")
texto = texto.replace("ã", "a")
texto = texto.replace("á", "a")
texto = texto.replace("ú", "u")
texto = texto.replace('*', '.jpg')
texto = texto.replace(('_'), ('\n'))

print(texto + '.jpg')
```

Comment: how are you planning to input several lines?

Comment: If I am not wrong , you just want to add ".jpg" after "_"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Wrap your input and processing code in a `while` loop:

```
while True:
    texto = input(str('\033[1;30mDigite ou cole o texto:')).strip().lower()

    # check if user wants to quit and break out of while loop if so.
    if texto == 'quit':
        break

    print('\033[1;33mPROCESSANDO...')
    
    #STEP DE ANÁLISE DE STR
    texto = texto.replace(" ", "-")
    texto = texto.replace("ã", "a")
    texto = texto.replace("á", "a")
    texto = texto.replace("ú", "u")
    texto = texto.replace('*', '.jpg')
    texto = texto.replace(('_'), ('\n'))
    
    print(texto + '.jpg')
```

As an aside you can use [`str.translate()`](https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/stdtypes.html?highlight=str%20translate#str.translate) to perform the substitutions on the input data. Although there is some setup required, this will be more efficient than calling `str.replace()` multiple times:

```
# set up translation table
TRANSLATIONS = ((" ", "-"),
                ("ã", "a"),
                ("á", "a"),
                ("ú", "u"),
                ('*', '.jpg'),
                ('_', '\n'))
trans_table = {ord(c): v for c,v in TRANSLATIONS}

while True:
    texto = input(str('\033[1;30mDigite ou cole o texto:')).strip().lower()

    # check if user wants to quit and break out of while loop if so.
    if texto == 'quit':
        break

    print('\033[1;33mPROCESSANDO...')
    print(texto.translate(trans_table) + '.jpg')
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Now it recognizes other lines, but returns it like this:

Comment: https://www.dropbox.com/sh/bl3a0kdakk2554v/AABvTYd0eV56MaXBduisE0Cea?dl=0

Comment: see the link, has the print with the result, I wish I could copy all the results, but it keeps repeating.